# Cannot use installed Blazor QuickGrid nuget package

Tags: c#, nuget-package, blazor-webassembly

I'm using Visual Studio 2022. My Blazor WebAssembly project uses .NET Core 7. I've installed the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Component.QuickGrid nuget package from the Package Manager and it appears in my Dependecencies/Package and it is included in the ItemsGroup of the project file.

However, when I try a @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Component.QuickGrid in my razor component, it doesn't reference it.

I've tried rebuilding the project and reloading VS, and reinstalling the package. Still no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should be able to install and use this version on 6.0 or 7.0 - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid/0.1.0-alpha.22351.1

Comment: I'll try that version in the link. In the meantime I'm using Smart.Blazor components

Answer (score 1):

Just checked, the recent Apr 11,2023 version of QuickGrid is targeting .NET Core 8.0 prerelease. This is probably the issue.